# Remove onItemTouchListener from a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` set up with custom rows. It has an `OnItemTouchListener` attached to it

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this, recyclerView, new MyClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            itemClick(position);
        }
    }));
```

At some point I need to remove this listener attach an another one.

With ListView, i can do:
`listView.setOnItemClickListener(null);`

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: remove the method and apply your click event in viewholder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

recycle view do provide method for this

```
recyclerView.removeOnItemTouchListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener listener=new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        }

recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(listener)
recyclerview.removeOnItemTouchListener(listener);
```